# jCenter returns 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: android, react-native, jcenter

I am trying to build my project but it seems the jcenter is down.

$ cd android
$ sudo ./gradlew assembleRelease

```
> Task :app:lintVitalRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-community_masked-view:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:+.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-community_masked-view
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

Comment: Can you add your **android/build.gradle** code?

Comment: Yeah, bintray is down!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70452454/react-native-buld-failed-with-the-following-message-failed-to-list-versions-for) helps?

Comment: use VPN or proxy

Answer (score 1):

[JCenter is going to shutdown](https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown) and now is READ-ONLY. And it is getting offline often causing issues with builds and pipelines.

#### In summary

You will require to update your `android/build.gradle` file to use `mavenCentral()` instead of `Jcenter()`.

As per Gradle documentation, JCenter is a mirror of Maven Central, so all of your dependencies should be there.

> JCenter is a central artifact repository, like Maven Central. Software
> projects use JCenter to distribute their software to other people.
> JCenter also serves as a mirror for Maven Central, so any dependencies
> available on Maven Central are also available on JCenter (but not vice
> versa).

#### A few things to consider:

- In case it is a **library** (e.g node_modules/react-native-appsflyer), pointing to Jcenter, that is giving you an error... I would advise you to check the library giving you an error has updated a new version with a fix. In case so, update to the new
  version to get the changes.
- In case **the library doesn't have versions with the fix**, if you are building in React-native using npm packages, you could potentially take advantage of `patch-package` [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package). Because there will a possibility the libraries have not yet released the update removing JCenter from `build.gradle`.

##### Applying the patch

You can apply the changes yourself using the Patch Package library. Documentation added in the end for reference.

1. Go to `node_modules/library-with-error/android/build.gradle`
2. Change `jcenter()` to `mavenCentral()`
3. Run: `npx patch-package library-with-error`
4. Git add, commit and push

#### Personal notes:

- I did advise the full removal of `JCenter` instead of adding MavenCentral() to the top because of the **shutdown** and that JCenter is often getting offline and giving timeout errors.

> Based on the current timeline, builds that use JCenter will be able to
> resolve dependencies until *February 1, 2022* without changes. After
> that date, *there are no guarantees that you will be able to build*
> your software if you continue to use JCenter."

- Also, Gradle is discouraging the usage of JCenter.

> "To discourage new projects from using JCenter, we will be removing
> JCenter from our samples and init templates. The new default will be
> Maven Central. Gradle itself has no inherent tie to JCenter or Maven
> Central, so you can always switch any other repository of your choice.
> This change will be effective with the next Gradle release – Gradle
> 7.0."

- In case of **dependencies (pom, jar)** are not added to Maven, here [are instructions on how to add](https://maven.apache.org/repository/guide-central-repository-upload.html). Add that to the PR with discussions to collaborate.

#### Useful Links

- Add `--use-yarn` to `patch-package` command in case your project uses [Yarn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package).
- Documentation using [Patch package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package).

Answer (score 0):

JFrog will keep JCenter as a read-only repository indefinitely. JCenter users and the community can continue to rely on JCenter as a reliable mirror for Java packages. You may visit https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Bintray+Migration+Guide
for further details.

Answer (score 0):

`android -> build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        all { ArtifactRepository repo ->
            if(repo instanceof MavenArtifactRepository){
                def url = repo.url.toString()
                if (url.startsWith('https://jcenter.bintray.com/')) {
                    remove repo
                }
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```